# CBOE Index Minute Data

Tags: volatility, data, implied-volatility, historical-data

I am doing a small research and looking for a place to purchase historical minute CBOE Index data. I am interested in:

VIX - CBOE Volatility Index
VVIX - CBOE VIX VOLATILITY INDEX
VXV - CBOE VIX VOLATILITY INDEX
VXST - CBOE Short-Term Volatility Index
VXMT - CBOE Mid-Term Volatility Index
VIN - CBOE Near-term VIX Index
VIF - CBOE Far-term VIX Index

Is there a reliable place of getting such data?

Comment: @Vitali_Halapjan Did this help you at all?

Answer (score 2):

### Yes,there is. **Key is how long you want to go back/need**

> **Educational**

If you are a student you can get the data from your school if you have access to a database known as WRDS (Wharton Research Data Services) (They have OptionMetrics) Other educational sources would be Thomson Reuters Sirca Tick Data and Bloomberg.

> **Non Educational**

**Nanex**
[Historical Data](http://www.nanex.net/historical.html)
[image: nanex cboe]

> **From CBOE ITSELF**

[Historical Options Data](https://datashop.cboe.com/option-quotes-intervals)
[image: purchase historical minute CBOE Index data]

---

Best of Luck!

Answer (score 0):

For VIX and VVIX you can try [FirstRate Data](http://firstratedata.com) which has 1-minute bars going back 5 years